# Change font style in HTML

Tags: doxygen

I have added several lines to my Doxygen file in order to make effect on generated HTML document font.

```
HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET=custom.css
HTML_STYLESHEET=custom.css
```

I places custom.css file in the same folder where Doxygen file is located.

Content of custom.css:

```
pre.code {
    line-height: 6; 
}
body {
    font-size: 55px; 
}
```

After executing doxygen command I got HTML documents without any font changes. What I do wrong?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? The `HTML_STYLESHEET` will replaced the default doxygen stylesheet and your stylesheet should only contain new / replcement etings and thus be in `HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET`. The `HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET` should be specified with with a relative path compaged to the place where doxygen is started or should contain a full qualified path.